# MySQL aggregate data IN, OUT times

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

I got in table something like this:

```
ID | UID | ACTION | URL | TIMESTAMP
```

Where ...

```
ID - primary key
UID - user id
ACTION - IN or OUT
URL - action URL
TIMESTAMP - action TIMESTAMP
```

How to aggregate all data with one query?

I mean... as output I would like table with `UID`,`URL`,`TOTAL_TIME` where `TOTAL_TIME` would be a sum of all times between `IN` and `OUT` of given URL...

I tried some custom functions, but without luck...

Example Input (timestamp simplified to show what I mean):

```
1|13|IN|http://www.gógle.koń|1
2|13|OUT|http://www.gógle.koń|5
...
13454|13|IN|http://www.gógle.koń|550
...
13465|13|OUT|http://www.gógle.koń|600
...
243252|13|IN|http://www.pr0nstaff.meh|tiny_leg_finger|1200
...
245431|13|OUT|http://www.pr0nstaff.meh/tiny_leg_finger|2200
```

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THERE MAY BE A CASE (AND SURELY WILL BE) WHERE `IN - OUT` OF ONE `URL` WOULD BE BROKEN BY `IN` OR `IN - OUT` OR `OUT` OF OTHER**
... so we canno't simply count from IN to OUT without checking the site match.

Output for example input (for `UUID = 13`) should be:

```
13|www.gógle.koń|14
13|http://www.pr0nstaff.meh/tiny_leg_finger|1000
```

Comment: The main problem is speed, not solution itself... there is like 30GB of data in there...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but I'm not shure, if there IN/OUT is not always double. So please check..

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
 id INT NOT NULL,
 uid INT NOT NULL,
 action VARCHAR(3),
 url varchar(100),
 timestamp1 TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES
( 1 , 13 , 'IN', 'www.go.com', '2015-01-07 08:00:00'),
( 2 , 13 , 'OUT', 'www.go.com', '2015-01-07 09:00:00'),
( 3 , 14 , 'IN', 'www.go2.com', '2015-01-07 08:30:00'),
( 4 , 14 , 'OUT', 'www.go2.com', '2015-01-07 09:00:00'),
( 5 , 15 , 'IN', 'www.go3.com', '2015-01-07 09:00:00'),
( 6 , 16 , 'OUT', 'www.go3.com', '2015-01-07 09:00:00');


SELECT i.uid,i.url,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, i.timestamp1, o.timestamp1)) AS diff_hour
FROM   (SELECT id,uid,url,timestamp1
        FROM   test1
        WHERE  action = 'IN') i
JOIN (SELECT id,uid,url,timestamp1
        FROM   test1
       WHERE  action = 'OUT') o
  ON i.uid = o.uid
 AND i.url = o.url
 AND i.id < o.id
GROUP  BY i.uid,i.url
ORDER  BY i.uid,i.url;
```

Comment: There may be posibility that there is IN without OUT, not sure about OUT without IN, but probably not... in such a case, after another IN, it should take date from the lastest IN before first OUT. For example IN IN OUT should take lastest IN and first OUT, but IN OUT OUT IN OUT should take first IN, first OUT, skip OUT without IN and then count last IN OUT pair. A bit complicated, but kind of natural in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT UID, URL, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, InTime, OutTime) AS TOTAL_TIME 
FROM (SELECT UID, URL, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'IN' THEN TIMESTAMP ELSE NULL END) InTime, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'OUT' THEN TIMESTAMP ELSE NULL END) OutTime
      FROM tableA 
      GROUP BY UID, URL
    ) AS A;
```

Comment: Not sure if it fits situation where there is something like this: IN1 www.com OUT1 www.com IN2 www.com OUT2 www.com ... that would count from IN1 to OUT2, wouldn't it?

Comment: Edited question to fit your needs, thanx